# Empty Bundle in the onSaveInstanceState method

Tags: android, onsaveinstancestate

I display pictures from moviesdb using volley in a gridview. The next step is have that gridview in the landscape mode too. So my logic behind this,is to store the list that contains the data as key value pair inside the onSaveInstantState method as:

```
 @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putParcelableArrayList("movies", moviesList);
    outState.putStringArrayList("images", images);
    Log.v("TAG","list size:" + moviesList.size());

}
```

The log output gives me a size of 20 which is correct. However when I am using the debugger, the line

```
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("movies", moviesList);
```

gives me an empty bundle. That's very strange! The images list works fine,and can see what's in there. Any ideas what is wrong?

Here is my code.

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
String BASE_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=my_key";
static public ArrayList<Movie> moviesList;
static public ArrayList<String> images;
static public MovieAdapter movieAdapter;
public static String imageIcon;
ImageView imageView;

static public String lastSortOrder;
static GridView gridview;

public MainFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState != null) {

        moviesList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("movies");
        images = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("images");
    }else{
        moviesList = new ArrayList<>();
        images = new ArrayList<>();
        movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity());
        updateMovies();
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    moviesList = new ArrayList<>();
    images = new ArrayList<>();
    gridview = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    int ot = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    gridview.setNumColumns(ot == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ? 3 : 2);
    gridview.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
    return rootView;
}

private void updateMovies(){

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
            BASE_URL,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("TAG", response.toString());

                    try {
                        JSONArray moviesArray = response.getJSONArray("results");

                        for (int i = 0; i < moviesArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject movie = moviesArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            Movie movieItem = new Movie();
                            movieItem.setTitle(movie.getString("title"));
                            movieItem.setId(movie.getInt("id"));
                            movieItem.setBackdrop_path(movie.getString("backdrop_path"));
                            movieItem.setOriginal_title(movie.getString("original_title"));
                            movieItem.setOriginal_language(movie.getString("original_language"));
                            if (movie.getString("overview") == "null") {
                                movieItem.setOverview("No Overview was Found");
                            } else {
                                movieItem.setOverview(movie.getString("overview"));
                            }
                            if (movie.getString("release_date") == "null") {
                                movieItem.setRelease_date("Unknown Release Date");
                            } else {
                                movieItem.setRelease_date(movie.getString("release_date"));
                            }
                            movieItem.setPopularity(movie.getString("popularity"));
                            movieItem.setVote_average(movie.getString("vote_average"));
                            movieItem.setPoster_path(movie.getString("poster_path"));
                            if (movie.getString("poster_path") == "null") {
                                movieItem.setPoster_path(API.IMAGE_NOT_FOUND);
                            } else {
                                images.add(API.IMAGE_URL + API.IMAGE_SIZE_185 + movie.getString("poster_path"));

                            }

                            moviesList.add(movieItem);
                            Log.v("TAG","list size:" + moviesList.size());
                            movieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putParcelableArrayList("movies", moviesList);
    outState.putStringArrayList("images", images);
    //Log.v("TAG","list size:" + moviesList.size());

  }



}
```

Thanks,

Theo.

Comment: I bet that `Movie` doesn't implement Parcelable properly

Comment: Yes. I think i found the mistake. I will come back to it tomorrow:)